# Is my application vulnerable to XSS?

Tags: javascript, xss

I am trying to test if my web application is vulnerable to javascript cross site scripting. In my text area, I am trying to run:
`<script type="text/javascript" >window.alert('I am here')</script>`.

However this doesn't get executed when the application is run. Does this mean that my application is not susceptible to XSS? Or what would be a better way to check if my application is vulnerable to javascript XSS?

Comment: You can find some resource on the OWASP site, e.g.: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Cross_site_scripting

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "trying to run code in text area". You need to check the code that processes the input and creates the output - if you need help with that, please post that code.

Comment: I did this test: deployed a test database, updated string columns with `<img src="broken" onerror="alert(N)" />` (where `N` - was unique for each column) and just clicked through the application. If alert appears - very likely it's a XSS vulnerability. Actually it's very rough test, but It was good enough first step to quickly identify multiple places, where user editable content wasn't escaped.